# Use library Activity as the main one

Tags: android, android-activity, android-library

Basically I want to run one of my library `Activities` as the `Main/Launcher` one in my final application.

For example:

- **Library A** contains an `Activity` named `DefaultMainActivity` which has its own `layout` and behaviour. This `Android Application` is set as a `Library` in the `Android Properties`.
- **Application B** doesn't contain any `Activity` (for the moment) but implements some `Services`. This `Application` depends on the previous `Library A`. It has been set in the `Android Properties`.

In the `Application B`, I've declared the following `Activity`:

```
<activity android:name="com.libaray.a.DefaultMainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I try to run the `Application B`, it throws an error near these methods:

```
layout_progress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_progress);
```

The `findViewById` method keeps returning a `null` object, which throws an `NPE`.

Is there any way to fix this ?

**EDIT:** As requested here is the layout of my `Activity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#DDDDDD">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_progress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_progress"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#5283CF"
            android:text="@string/misc_loading" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_progress"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the layout of DefaultMainActivity.

Comment: If the xml you posted is set as Content View for DefaultMainActivity, it should not throw NPE. I need to see the exception stack.

Comment: The issue has been fixed on its own. I don't know why, how nor what. but it's fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning and re-launching Eclipse made the job.